# Apple Watch Connectivity Status with iPhone

Tags: iphone, swift, watchos, watchconnectivity

I am trying to get the connectivity status of the iPhone and the Apple Watch. I have tried using CoreBluetooth which didn't work. I think I am on the right track but I need a bit of help. My code is below :)

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            let session = WCSession.default
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }

    return true
}
```

Detail.swift

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (WCSession.default.isPaired){
        print("thumbsup")
    } else{
       print("thumbsdown")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you also have to check whether the activation state is active, otherwise *isPaired* should not be evaluated